# How to have succinct and correct version of error handling in succinct and correct version of functional pipelining in scala?

Tags: scala

[effective scala style](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Collections-Style) states the following:

> this is both succinct and correct, but nearly every reader will have a
>   difficult time recovering the original intent of the author. A
>   strategy that often serves to clarify is to name intermediate results
>   and parameters:

```
val votesByLang = votes groupBy { case (lang, _) => lang }
val sumByLang = votesByLang map { case (lang, counts) =>
  val countsOnly = counts map { case (_, count) => count }
  (lang, countsOnly.sum)
}
val orderedVotes = sumByLang.toSeq
  .sortBy { case (_, count) => count }
  .reverse
```

what I fail to understand is in this style if i have errors while evaluating the value for `votesByLang`, `sumByLang`, ... how can I have a single `recover` at the end after all if i just had .map.map ... I could have a single `recover` at the end.  So is it possible to have a single recover also with this style? (and not only possible but with good style...)

Or in other words what is the succinct and correct error handling in this succinct and correct functional pipelining code?

you see with the non-concise version i'm able to code this:

```
object MyRealMainObj extends App {

  println(
    Try(1)
      .map(doOne)
      .map(doTwo)
      .recover { // non succinct version can catch any prior error how to achieve the same in succinct version
        case e: Throwable => println("recovering from: " + e.getMessage)
    }
  )

  def doOne(i: Int): Int = { i + 1; throw new RuntimeException("failed in one") }
  def doTwo(i: Int): Int = { i + 2; throw new RuntimeException("failed in two") }
}
```

a single `recover` will catch any previous error in the `.map` but with the concise-succinct how can I achieve the same in concise and succinct way?

Comment: You're still calling `.map`, you're just naming the intermediate values. `.recover` at the end will behave exactly the same as it always would. No?

Comment: with multiple `.map` i can have 10 of them and at the end a single `.recover`  but with every operation getting into a `val` i don't see how to have a single `.recover` at the end see my editing of the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you expect some sort of scope to be magically created by .recover. This is not the case. With some minor simplifications, `Try(expr)`  is

```
try {
   val result = expr
   Success(result)
catch {
   e => Failure(e)
}
```

`tryResult.map(f)` is :

```
tryResult match {
   case Success(x) => Try(f(x))
   case f: Failure => f
}
```

`tryResult.recover(f)`  is

```
tryResult match {
  case Failure(e) if f.isDefinedAt(e) => Try(f(e))
  case other => other
}
```

There is no special magic. At every stage, you have values, not code in the scope of some try/catch. Putting those values in val will not change a thing. If you "debug by hand", you will notice that you get a Success object, then at some point, one of your map may fail and return a Failure, the following ones will keep being failures, and then when you pass the last one to recover, it may go back to Success. Settings vals in between cannot make any difference.

Comment: I see this means there is a Major drawback to using the concise and succinct version of code as suggested by effective scala because this makes my life harder with `recover` and most probably with more constructs! they should have mentioned this major drawback so that I can consider when to use it and when not to!

Comment: Could you explain what the drawback is?

Comment: Got it no drawback as i can do the `recover` on the last `val` and it will `catch` errors also from first.